# C++ array logic issue

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and need some help understanding the output of this program:

```
#include<iostream.h> 

int main(){
     int totalAge = 0;
     int age[10];

     for(int j= 1; j<10; j++){
              age[j] = j;
             cout << age[j] << endl;
     }

     for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
             totalAge = age[i];
           cout << "Total Age is : " << totalAge << endl;           
     }
     system("pause");
}
```

The output on the command prompt is this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Total Age is : 1700868285
Total Age is : 1
Total Age is : 2
Total Age is : 3
Total Age is : 4
Total Age is : 5
Total Age is : 6
Total Age is : 7
Total Age is : 8
Total Age is : 9

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why does it show `Total Age is : 1700868285`? I believe it should be `Total Age is : 0`.

Comment: `iostream.h` has never been a standard header. Use `iostream`. Your book should have also mentioned that arrays start at 0.

Comment: Your indexes start from 1 while assigning and from 0 while reading.

Comment: I did write so many programs with iostream.h, please any other suggestion?

Comment: Local values are uninitialized and you must take care of it yourself - your problem is that you assign values from index 1, not from 0, but read from 0.

Comment: By the way, despite the downvotes, your question is definitely a lot better than most I see. Please continue to provide short, complete code examples, expected output, and actual output. I'd wager the downvotes are just because this is something you should learn from whatever book/tutorial/class you're using.

Comment: this was the first question i have posted here. but now i will post here again, people start discouraging me by down voting.

Comment: Dont worry bro @user3779750. As you are new try out some tutorials and improve your knowledge in c++. Then start posting your doubts but dont just post simple questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you loop is this

```
 for(int j= 1; j<10; j++){
          age[j] = j;
         cout << age[j] << endl;
 }
```

It means you have skipped this position  age[0] because j=1 from first iteration. That is why compiler is showing garbage right there.
So you need to do this change

```
 for(int j= 0; j<10; j++){   
          age[j] = j;
         cout << age[j] << endl;
 }
```

Means only you need to do j=0 and rest of the things are already done.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `age[0]`. Your first loop starts from `j = 1`. How do you expect the compiler to magically determine that you want `age[0] = 0` when you never set it?

Comment: @chris: To my knowledge, most C++ compilers would as well, but it is still undefined behavior and it could set it to any number it wanted to. You can't expect it to be zero.

Comment: @wolfPack88, Of course. I'm just saying the compiler could magically determine you want 0 for uninitialized data if it went with the flow of most of the newer languages.

Answer (score 1):

//Change here to

```
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int totalAge = 0;
    int age[10];

    //Changed here from 1 to 0
    for(int j= 0 ; j<10; j++){
        age[j] = j;
        cout << age[j] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        totalAge = age[i];
        cout << "Total Age is : " << totalAge << endl;           
    }
}
```

Here's my results

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Total Age is : 0
Total Age is : 1
Total Age is : 2
Total Age is : 3
Total Age is : 4
Total Age is : 5
Total Age is : 6
Total Age is : 7
Total Age is : 8
Total Age is : 9
```

Comment: Thanks... First day answering stackoverflow "/

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop starts from 1 .So the first valve of the array contain garbage values as it is not initialiased.

You read using the second loop starting from 0 and prints the first value of the array which is uninitialised.Thats why the problem is caused